# Remove incoming links from duplicate website

Tags: googlebot

There is a duplicate development website that exists for legacy reasons and is pending a complete removal, it always had a rule in it's robots.txt file to deny all search engines, but at one point the robots.txt got deleted by accident, and for a point in time there were two cross-domain duplicates and Google indexed the entire duplicate website, and caused thousands of incoming links to the production website to show up in Google webmaster tools (Your site on the web > Links to your site).

The robots.txt got restored, and the entire development site is protected by a password, but the incoming links from the duplicate site remain in the production website webmaster tools, even though the development site robots.txt was downloaded by Google 19 hours ago.

I have spent hours reading about this, and see a lot of contradiction on the web, so would like to get an updated consensus from stackoverflow on how to perform a complete site removal and remove the links that point from the development site to the production site from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will be able to tell you exactly how much time will it take for Google to remove the "bad" links from index, but it's likely going to take a few days not hours. Another thing to keep in mind is that only "good" crawlers will be actually honoring your robots.txt file, so if you don't want these links to show up elsewhere, just using disallow in your robots.txt file certainly won't be enough.